# How do search engines link a url to a street address for their map view?

Tags: seo

For instance, you search for 'company x, Austin TX' and Google returns a map at the top of the page with a marker on it, the location of company x, and company x's website. How is that information collected? Does someone at the business address have to somehow manually associate the physical address with a web address?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data is collected **first** by telephone companies who make available the name, address, city, state, zip, and phone number (think phone books). Beyond that, any extra data like websites, images, descriptions are collected by various services and shared.

Answer (score 0):

If you start putting your number in the phone book you tend to get spammed, at least in the UK. http://google.com/local/add is where you can add your business details to google.